# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined ReactJS API calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I have recently been trying to play with APIs in React.js,
I believed the below code would have worked, based on a tutorial from https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html, However when I run this code I keep getting

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Below is my code, this is a component called DOTA and is exported to my App.js

```
import React from 'react';

const API_KEY ="some-api-key";
const DEFAULT_QUERY = 'redux';

class DOTA extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      info: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API_KEY + DEFAULT_QUERY)
      .then(response => response.json(console.log(response)))
     .then((result) => {
     console.log(result)    
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            info: result.info
          });
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }



render() {
const { error, isLoaded, info } = this.state;
if (error) {
  return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
} else if (!isLoaded) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
} else {
  return (
    <ul>
      {this.props.info.map(item => (
        <li key={ item.all_word_counts}>

        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
  }
}

export default DOTA
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DOTA from './components/DOTA/DOTA'
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <DOTA  />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have looked on here already for an answer but I can't seem to find someone with the same issue. Do I need to run **.map()** outside of JSX? Above the render? Or am I just missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be "this.state.info"

Comment: OP destructing `info` from state, so it should be just `info`.

Answer (score 0):

`DOTA` component does not get any `props` but you are trying to `map` over `this.props.info`. Actually you are destructing `info` from your state top of your render.

Here how this works. `info` is in the state and you are destructing it as:

```
const { error, isLoaded, info } = this.state;
```

This grabs `error`, `isLoaded` and `info` from state and assign it variables. So, you can use `info` instead of `this.state.info`. Actually you are using `error` like this top of `if` block.

So, use it in the related part like:

```
<ul>
      {info.map(item => (
        <li key={ item.all_word_counts}>

        </li>
      ))}
</ul>
```

But, with your current code, there is not any value inside your `li`s. I hope your are just testing right now.

**Update after comments**

Your problem seems with your data fetching. As long as you have an empty `info` state this value can't be undefined and your map works. This is how we generally avoid those `map of undefined` errors. If we can't have an empty state then we do conditional rendering.

If you want to test this case just comment out your `componentDidMount` method and try your code. It works. Of course it says `Loading` since you are not setting it to `true`. If you manually set it to `true` then you will see an empty page but not an error.

Here is a working example with your code but with another fetch:
https://codesandbox.io/s/q9jx3ro7y9

So, you should debug your `fetch`.

Comment: Hi @devserkan, I changed it to just be info.map and placed a value inside the li's, However, I still get the same error.  

Yes, I am still new to React, This is definitely just testing.

Comment: Hi. Can we see your updated code? With this current code you should not get `undefined` error since there is a defined empty `info` array in your state. If possible can you add your project to https://codesandbox.io ?

Comment: Here is my code on [codesandbox ](https://codesandbox.io/s/v3z0k6z743), I removed my API key for obvious reasons, But the error stays the same. Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer. Problem is in your fetch method.

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer helped then maybe you consider accepting it.